# como implementar recaptcha v3 en proyecto de angular

Tags: angular7, angular-material, recaptcha

Tengo un proyecto en angular para visualizar registros, lo quiero proteger con recaptcha v3 no tengo ningún formulario solo hace una petición de las registros, alguna idea?

probé en el index.html

```
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6Lcg38MnAAAAAGYc-W-CbGXqnYN2wCOjfckQH2sV"></script>
```

y en el ngOnInit de mi componente

```
grecaptcha.ready(() => {
      grecaptcha.execute('6Lcg38MnAAAAAGYc-W-CbGXqnYN2wCOjfckQH2sV', { action: 'homepage' }).then((token: string) => {
       console.log(token);
      });
    });
```

pero no veo que suban las estadísticas en mi administrador de recaptcha.